# Transforming the Area of Integration in the Beta Function

Tags: integration

My text derived the Beta function by change of variable and the Jacobian determinant.
$$\Gamma(x)\Gamma (y) = \int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{\infty} e^{-s-t} \space t^{x-1} \space s^{y-1} dt ds$$
Let $t = u(1-v)$ and $s = uv$.  Then $ 0 \le u < {\infty}$ and $0 \le v \le 1$. 
How did the boundary of $u, v$ become as such?

Now, I have that $u = t + s$.  So when either $t$ or $s$ goes to infinity, so does $u$. 
Then, $v = {s \over {s+t}} = {1 \over {1+(t/s)}}$, but dow do you justify that $v$ goes to $1$ when $t, s$ approach infinity?

Comment: Try writing $(u,v)=(u(t,s),v(t,s))$ and map through it the region $\left[0,\infty\right)\times \left[0,\infty\right)$ to check it's boundary. Edit: note that $v=1-\dfrac{t}{t+s}$ and for $t=0$ (part of the boundary of the original region), you have $v(0,s)=1$.

Comment: So you're not supposed to take both $t$ and $s$ to infinity as the same time ....  This may be where I got confused.  In a bounded region, you will not have a problem like this.

Comment: Points $(t,s)$ with large $t$ and $s$ are not mapped to the boundary of the new region. For example, $(t,s)=(10^{99},10^{99})$ are mapped to a point $(u,v)$ with $v< 1$. So, with the observation of the previous post, you note that every point $(u(t,s),v(t,s))$ with $(t,s)\in\left[0,\infty\right)\times\left[0,\infty\right)$ is such that $0\leq u(t,s)$ and $0\leq v(t,s)\leq 1$. Now also note that the boundary of $\left[0,\infty\right)\times \left[0,\infty\right)$ is mapped to the boundary of $\left[0,\infty\right)\times \left[0,1 \right]$ (just a calculation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is to maximize and minimize the two functions

$$  u=t+s,v={\frac {s}{t+s}},\quad 0\leq t \leq \infty,\, 0\leq s \leq \infty. $$

The first one is easy to see its max and min. For the second one, we shift to the polar coordinates $t=r\cos(\theta)$ and $s=r\sin(\theta)$ which implies

$$ v=\frac{\sin(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)+\cos(\theta)},\quad \theta \in [0,\pi/2]. $$

Now, the min and max of the above function is $0$, $1$.

Comment: TY all, got it.

Comment: @AndyTam: You are welcome. By the way, consider accepting the answer if you like it.